# What does RepeatedKFold actually mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

Say `n_repeats=5` and the number of fold is 3 (`n_splits=3`).

Does that mean the validator is creating 3-folds for our estimator/model to use every fold (like what KFold is for), then repeating that process for 5 times?

That means our model will use a total of 5 x 3 = 15 folds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can basically achieve the same effect by calling `KFolds.split()` `n_repeats` times in a loop.

Example setup:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Then running:

```
rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=1, random_state=2652124)
for train_index, test_index in rkf.split(X):
  print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

... produces:

```
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
```

... just like `KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=2652124)` would. Changing to `n_repeats=2` produces:

```
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [1 2] TEST: [0 3]
TRAIN: [0 3] TEST: [1 2]
```

And so on.

Comment: I just found out the answer from the doc too and figured out the rationale. Also, thank you for the suggestion of calling KFold in a loop for the same effect!

Comment: If we change `n_repeats=2` in `RepeatedKFold` and `n_splits=4` in `Kfold`, the results are not the same. What am i missing here?